# How do I customize the before_filer :authenticate_user! from Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, email

I want to add url in emails that I'm sending to my users. I want to pass a parameter for their email like Facebook does so that the login email field will already be populated.

I figure if I pass this as a parameter in the url I should be able to handle it in the :authenticate_user! before_filter. If the user is not logged in then I can use that parameter to populate the field in the login form.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the example of [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) you can add a token to the url.

the controller that handles that url which can inherit from Devise::SessionsController
and would find the user by the token and then show a costumized sign in form for the user

something like

```
# GET /users/sign_in
class MyAutoLoginController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    @user = User.find_by_token(params[:token]
    super
  end
```

Comment: That could work, but I still want users to have to enter their password, just in case someone else get hold of the email.

Comment: even better. I updated my response. the general idea is still the same, inherit sessionController and customize the actions/views